# Kony Reference Error :- Can't find variable: testCall

Tags: javascript, temenos-quantum

In my code i have a simple drop down, on select of which i am calling a function called testCall() , But for some reason i am seeing a reference error :- cant find variable: testCall , Can any one please help

code below

```
function testCall(){

    //print statements
    //kony.print("test");

}
```

screen shots 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code that calls `testCall()` ?

Comment: Can you post the html of the select drop down as well.

Comment: there is no code, but i have attached the screen shots from kony studio how the events are triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is any error in your function of the entire js file, such errors appear, in my case i had a single equals in a if condition which was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your .js (module) contains some java-script error (most probably syntax error). Better you can copy all the java-script code and put it in chrome console it will show you the syntax error.